# Google Maps don't render the whole map upon full screen

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, fullscreen

I'm having some problems with the resize of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. If I set the CSS "parameters" right on load (just in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld)) the map will show 100% height and width - no problem. But when I try to get the same result by clicking on a link it's not showing the whole map.

[image: This is how the map shows upon click on the link to toggle full screen]

I have tested both `css()` and `toggleClass()` in jQuery on this event. `toggleClass()` makes the map goes invisible (hides the map completely rather than makes it full screen) with this code:

```
// jQuery
$('#weather-map').toggleClass('test');

// CSS
#weather-map.test {
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    position : absolute;
    z-index : 200;
}
```

`css()` works (the map goes full screen) but the image above shows how the map renders upon full screen:

```
$('#weather-map').css({
                       'height' : '100%',
                       'width' : '100%',
                       'top' : '0',
                       'left' : '0',
                       'position' : 'absolute',
                       'z-index' : '200'
                      });
```

I wonder now, why does it act like this? Have I missed something or is this method not the right one to toggle full screen of the map?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just because of how Google's mapping Javascript works.  It renders based on the container's size, and doesn't add any kind of handler to re-render in case the container gets re-sized thereafter.  I imagine that in your example above, you'd have to just call the map initialization code a second time to render the map again in your resized div.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer fixed my problem and I will accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: I had this issue a few weeks ago - very annoying and also hard to fix. It's just a matter of making the container the larger size to start with, then shrink down - vs. start small and grow large.

Comment: Even better is to trigger a resize event, google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); - this causes the API to recompute its dimensions. Just run this right after resizing the container.

Comment: +1 for barryhunter, and better to setCenter again after triggering resize.